# Read a CSV line by line and unmarshal it to a struct

Tags: csv, go

I have a 8 gigs CSV file that i need to unmarshal to a list of struct

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"

    gocsv "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
    dto "github.com/toto/GeoTransport/import/dto"
)

// Put in parameter json the csv names
func importAdresse() {
    var adressesDB []dto.GeoAdresse
    clientsFile, err := os.OpenFile("../../../data/geo/public.geo_adresse.csv", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE, os.ModePerm)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    gocsv.SetCSVReader(func(in io.Reader) gocsv.CSVReader {
        r := csv.NewReader(in)
        r.Comma = ';'
        return r // Allows use pipe as delimiter
    })
    if err = gocsv.UnmarshalFile(clientsFile, &adressesDB); err != nil { // Load clients from file
        panic(err)
    }
    var i int
    i = 0
    for _, adresse := range adressesDB {
        fmt.Println("adresse.Numero")
        fmt.Printf("%+v\n", adresse)
        fmt.Println(adresse.Numero)
        i++
        if i == 3 {
            break
        }
    }
}

func init() {
}

func main() {
    importAdresse()
}
```

Actually I am using go csv to unmarshall it but I have some memory error.

The program quit because it does not have enough ram.

I would like to know how to read the csv line by line and unmarshal it to a struct.

One of the solution will be to split the CSV file with some unix command.

But I would like to know how to do it with only Go.

Comment: "I have some memory error" -- What error? Show the problem you need help with.

Comment: `encoding/csv` already reads a CSV file line by line. What actual problem do you need help solving?

Comment: @Flimzy i d'ont have enough ram visibly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the parsing method you're using [attempts to read the entire CSV file into memory](https://github.com/gocarina/gocsv/blob/67c824bc04d4d983e87084beb7bd07a935cdaf9b/decode.go#L145). You might try using the [standard CSV reader package](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv) directly, or using another CSV-to-struct library that allows for line-by-line decoding like [this one](https://github.com/jszwec/csvutil). Does the example code on those pages show what you're looking for?

Another thing to try would be running `wc -l ../../../data/geo/public.geo_adresse.csv` to get the number of lines in your CSV file, then write this:

```
var adressesDB [<number of lines in your CSV>]dto.GeoAdresse
```

If the runtime raises the out of memory exception on that line, it means that the unmarshalled CSV data exceeds your RAM capacity and you'll have to read it in chunks.